# How to change core functionality on DotNetNuke 7

Tags: dotnetnuke

I search this question on uncle google, and in this site, but didn't find a explicit answer.

Can you guys teach me how to make an extension point from an existing core functionality on dotnetnuke7?

For example, I want to change the default behaviour of the "add new page" functionality, implementing different permissions according to user's profile.

Sorry for any English mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DNN is open source meaning you can download the [source code](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/110757) and check under the hood how things are done. Then you can make a module that has a custom implementation of what you want to do. Every good module developer always has a copy of the source code for reference. Otherwise you are asking someone to do the work for you. Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, maybe i didn't explain well my question. I entered the example in attempt to explain better my question. I want to use the PRO version, so there is no source code avaiable, I just wanna figure out if i can do an extension of their classes to make my own code

Comment: The pro version and the community version are fundamentally the same, except the pro has a few enhancements that are missing in the community edition. I would suppose the code for page creation and management in DNN Pro is essentially the same as in DNN CE. community version